# ExtJS4: How to make horizontal menu?

Tags: menu, extjs4

I'm trying to implement simple drop-down menu in ExtJS4.

By default it appears vertically and it seem like there is no (obvious) way to make it appearing horizontally.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by horizontal menu? You can add a bunch of buttons on the toolbar ...
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/menu/menus.html

Comment: Tnanks for reply. I know this is possible, there are some official examples. I just doubt if it's possible to implement something like this http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/ext-core-latest/examples/menu/ using this approach.

Comment: You are over thinking this :) All you need to do is add items on the toolbar - by default they are buttons but you can specify  other xtypes. As you add the buttons you can add subitems to them and they turn into menues. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/menu/menus.html

Comment: You are welcome. here is an interesting example with a bunch of fields in the toolbar instead of menus....just to give you ideas. http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/PhAbR/embedded/result/ remove the last 2 tokens in the URL to see the source

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it. Menu ignore layout config and always use `vbox`. To display it horizontally you should override `initComponent` to make possible switching between `hbox` and `vbox`. When you choose `hbox` items will be displayed horizontally, but the size will remain like in the vbox. So there is also necessary to do something with sizing - to do that you should override `doConstrain` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I will try to implement this solution and let you know if everything is ok.